# RPi2 - Taking images while recording video

Tags: python, python-3.x, video, raspberry-pi, video-capture

In an effort to make a simple surveillance camera I want to record video as long as there is movement. For that I need to analyze an images every second or so. I would like to start capturing video and stop only after deciding that there is no more movement, for that I need to capture an image while video is recording.

What is the easiest way to do this on RPi2-Python3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Picamera has a 'built in' solution for this

```
import picamera

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.resolution = (800, 600)
    camera.start_preview()
    camera.start_recording('foo.h264')
    camera.wait_recording(10)
    camera.capture('foo.jpg', use_video_port=True)
    camera.wait_recording(10)
    camera.stop_recording()
```

taken from:
http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.10/recipes2.html#capturing-images-whilst-recording

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here:
Identifying motion, and recording video.

To identify motion, one (naive but simple) approach is to capture a frame every second, apply a filter (gaussian blur) to get rid of noise which would cause a false alarm, and then compare one frame to the one after.

More sophisticated approaches involve subtracting the background. See [here](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/05/25/basic-motion-detection-and-tracking-with-python-and-opencv/) for one, specifically in the context of a surveillance camera

To record the video, see these posts: [1](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/22/writing-to-video-with-opencv/),[2](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/01/home-surveillance-and-motion-detection-with-the-raspberry-pi-python-and-opencv/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my problem is not with the motion, it is with the recording video. The question is technical and not mathematical...

Comment: @Gilad try the second part of the blog post.... http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/01/home-surveillance-and-motion-detection-with-the-raspberry-pi-python-and-opencv/

Comment: This is a nice post but the output is not video but stand alone images. One might say that it is possible to write these standalone images to a stream and make a video but I'm looking for an easier solution before I do that

Comment: @Gilad https://www.google.com.au/search?q=record+video+rpi&oq=record+video+rpi&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3.5563j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8